# Are days longer than nights in Phantom Pain?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Unless I don't really know how to estimate durations, I noticed that day time in Phantom Pain seems longer than the night. I'm currently still doing the Afghanistan missions.

For example, if the mission starts at night, I have about seven minutes before sunrise.

Seven minutes usually is the time to get *S* rank.

Are days really longer than nights?

Comment: We're starting to drift into the whole game design territory here, so it might be worth clarifying your question; do you mean is it intentional for the game to only give you that much time?  Or is it intentionally designed that way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done 10-15 minute missions entirely at night. I think this is just a perception issue.

Answer (score 8):

As @twobugs said, night begins at 18:00 and day begins at 06:00. At least, that's the case internally.

In reality, the engine is still rendering the sun at 18:00, and starts rendering it again somewhere between 05:00 and 06:00. That's why daytime appears to last longer than nighttime.

However, even though the sun is already shining brightly at 06:00, enemies still can't see you very well until the engine officially acknowledges sunrise. In other words: As long as Mother Base doesn't say "*Sun is about to rise*", you can still sneak around as if it were night outside. Daytime and nighttime are therefore equal in length.

Comment: Ouch right in the immersion

Answer (score 2):

According to the iDroid they are approximately the same length.

The sun sets around 18:00 hours each and rises at 06:00 the next morning. As far as I can tell anytime before sunrise but after sunset is considered "night", and before sunset but after sunrise is "day". There may be some slight variation between the lengths, but it's not a profound difference.